# Using ngx-vis in angular 14 project

Tags: angular

In angular 14 when importing `VisTimelineDirective` in a standalone component I get the following error:

```
 Component imports must be standalone components,
 directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.
```

the `vis-timeline.directive.d.ts` is missing the `Directive` declaration

EDIT:

Importing the VisTimelineDirective into a module gives the following error:

```
 'VisTimelineDirective' does not appear to be an NgModule class
```

Adding `VisTimelineDirective` to declarations in a module gives the following error:

```
 Cannot declare 'VisTimelineDirective' in an NgModule 
as it's not a part of the current compilation.
```

Importing `VisModule` in standalone component gives the following error:

```
    Component imports must be standalone components,
directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.
```

Importing `VisModule` in a module gives the following error:

```
'VisModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can import `VisTimelineDirective` into a `VisVendorModule` and than import module into your standalone component

Comment: tried that. it gives an error about VisTimelineDirective not being a module.

Comment: directives goes into `declarations` not into `imports`

Comment: tried that too, I updated the question

Comment: that error seems like he already declare it into a internal library, i think you can import library module directly into you standalone component (i don't know module name, but for sure you already imported it)

Comment: ngx-vis exports only two directive according to https://github.com/visjs/ngx-vis/issues/319#issuecomment-1249081746

Comment: if you import `VisTimelineModule` into your standalone component what happen?

Comment: the term VisTimelineModule  does not exist in ngx-vis source code

Comment: sorry, try with `VisModule`

Comment: importing VisModule in standalone component: Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.